# Unlock layers in adobe muse

Tags: adobe, layer, unlock, muse

I want to change the logo and text in adobe muse. But in adobe muse all layers are locked. How can I unlock these layers. I am using this option but  it not unlock the layers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've pos got this sorted by now, though some times you have to select all the layers and unlock them that way.

nother things is that they could be locked on the Master Page so you may need to unlock them on there to move and edit them and not on the actual page itself.

With templates, most of the design elements are on the Master pages not on the actual  Homepage etc..

Cheers